# How do I verify that my model is actually functioning correctly in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of around 6K chemical formulas which I am preprocessing via Keras' tokenization to perform binary classification. I am currently using a 1D convolutional neural network with dropouts and am obtaining an accuracy of 82% and validation accuracy of 80% after only two epochs. No matter what I try, the model just plateaus there and doesn't seem to be improving at all. Those same exact accuracies are reached with a vanilla LSTM too. What else can I try to improve my accuracies? Losses only have a difference of 0.04... Anyone have any ideas? Both models use an embedding layer and changing the output dimension isn't having an effect either.

Comment: Probably something wrong with processing data, or model setup. Did you look at the prediction? If there all the same then it's not doing anything

Answer (score 2):

According to your answer, I believe your model has a high bias and low variance (see [this link](http://www.learnopencv.com/bias-variance-tradeoff-in-machine-learning/) for further details). Thus, your model is not fitting your data very well and it is causing **underfitting**. So, I suggest you 3 things:

1. **Train your model a little longer**: I believe two epoch are too few to give a chance to your model understand the patterns in the data. Try to minimize learning rate and increase the number of epochs.
2. **Try a different architecture**: you may change the amount of convolutions, filters and layers, You can also use different activation functions and other layers like *max pooling*.
3. **Make an error analysis**: once you finished your training, apply your model to test set and take a look into the errors. How much false positives and false negatives do you have? Is your model better to classify one class than the other? You can see a pattern in the errors that may be related to your data?

Finally, if none of these suggestions helped you, you may also try to increase the number of features, if possible.

Comment: I think one of the reasons might have been my data which was imbalanced - as soon as I under sampled one of the classes, the model started behaving normally

Comment: I assumed your data was already balanced as you didn't specify it in the question. Glad to see it helped though.